# Get Application Scripts directory for app group

Tags: cocoa, foundation

For the current app, I can get the Application Scripts directory with `FileManager.url(for: .applicationScriptsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)`, but I cannot find a similar API for application groups. Does one exist, or do I have to construct the URL manually? That would probably be `~/Library/Application Scripts/[app group id]`, but there doesn't seem to be a `FileManager` API to access `~` either, as `FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser` returns `/Users/username/Library/Containers/[app id]/Data/`.

Answer (score 0):

It does exist in FileManager

[`containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412643-containerurl)

Comment: Yes, but how do you build the Application Scripts path from there? Simply appending `/Library/Application Scripts` doesn't work, since running `try NSUserScriptTask(url: scriptURL).execute()` throws an error `NSCocoaErrorDomain code 257: The file [...] couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.`

Comment: The application scripts cannot be synchronized by app groups. If you have widgets you – actually the user – have to copy the scripts in both Application Scripts folders.

Comment: PS: See this post the developer forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/109279 Nothing has changed in the last 5 years.

Comment: So it's apparently not possible, although it's strange that an Application Scripts directory is created automatically even for app groups. You might want to add your comment as an answer.